# Embedding torsion units of an order into torsion units of the reduced order.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be an order, i.e. a commutative ring of which the additive group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for a certain non-negative integer $n$. Show that there exists an embedding
$$A^{\times}_{\text{tor}}\ \hookrightarrow\ (A_{\text{red}})^{\times}_{\text{tor}},$$
where $A^{\times}_{\text{tor}}$ is the group of torsion units of $A$, and $A_{\text{red}}=A/\sqrt{0_A}$ is the reduced ring of $A$.

Edit: In response to a reply which seems to have been removed; I understand that the quotient map $A\rightarrow A_{\text{red}}$ restricts to a group homomorphism $A^{\times}_{\text{tor}}\rightarrow(A_{\text{red}})^{\times}_{\text{tor}}$, but I am unable to show that this map is injective.

Comment: You're right, I forget one needs to show the quotient map is injective!

Answer (score 5):

Since this is homework, let me give a hint:

If $a$  lies in the kernel of your map, show that you may write $a = 1 + x$
for some nilpotent $x$.  Now write $a^n = 1$ for some $n$, deduce a corresponding
equation involving $x$, and see where it leads.

Added: Since the OP has now solved the question, let me sketch the answer, based
on the discussion in the comments:

$(1+x)^n = 1$ implies that $nx + $ higher order terms in $x = 0$.  From this it is easy to deduce that $x = 0,$ given that $x$ is nilpotent.  (The OP's gives the following very succinct approach: we may factor out $x$ in the above equation to get $x (n + $ terms involving positive powers of $x) = 0$, and the parenthetical factor is a non-zero divisor in $A$ (since $n$ is not a zero-divisor, and $x$ is nilpotent).)

As an aside, note that
the assumption that $A$ is torsion-free as an abelian group (this is what is really used; of course it follows directly from the assumption that $A$ is an order) is crucial.  There are char. $p$ examples where the given map is *not* injective.  One of the simplest is obtained by taking $A = \mathbb F_p[x]/(x^p).$

Comment: @user: Dear user, What did you try?  Regards,

Comment: @user30382: Dear user, Your first four lines are on the right track, but you then move in a direction that is not relevant. (Why would you want to solve for $x^n$?) Remember that you are trying to prove that $x = 0$ (so wouldn't it make more sense to solve for $x$?), and what you know is that some power of $x$ equals $0$.  Take the equation $x^n + \cdots + n x = 0$, and use it to deduce that $x = 0$.  (Why don't you begin by imagining that $x^2 = 0$, and see what you can say.  After that, suppose that $x^3 = 0$ and see what happens.  You should then see how to proceed in general.)  Regards,

Comment: @user30382: Dear user, You're welcome (and the observation about obtaining a unit is a nice way to see it; I had in mind a somewhat clunkier argument by induction on the degree of nilpotence of $x$).  Best wishes,

Comment: @user30382: Dear user, One more thing; note that the assumption that $A$ is an order is crucial, because this allows you to deduce that $x=0$ from the *a priori* weaker statement that $n x =0$.  (So really what is used is that $A$ is torsion-free as an abelian group.)  Best wishes,

Comment: @user30382: P.S. Also, you have to be a little careful in how your phrase your argument, because $n$ does not dividie $n$ choose $i$ in general if $n$ is not prime (e.g. $4$ does not divide $6$, which is $4$ choose $2$).   I have added a sketch of the argument to my answer, which phrases things slightly differently to avoid this minor annoyance.